# Does the system do a retain on object in performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: when no wait?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsthread

Consider the following code - obviously non-ARC:

```
.  
.  
.  
NSString* someValueToSend= [NSString alloc] initWithString@"Send me! Will I survive?"];  

if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(giveMeYourString:)])  
{  
  [delegate performSelector:@selector(giveMeYourString:) onThread:someOtherThread withObject:someValueToSend waitUntilDone:NO];  
}  
[someValueToSend release];  
.  
.  
.
```

Depending on what else is going on in the application, the delegate may or may not get around to running that selector before someValueToSend is released. Does the "system" do a "courtesy" retain on the object?

If not, and I am in a situation where I cannot block, what is a good strategy for sending a value across the boundary without a leak? Autorelease?

I did find a reference elsewhere that said the object is retained, but I have not seen that in the documentation....

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the system will retain the object.

And, no, `autorelease` can *never* be used to protect an object from being released across a thread boundary.   Technically, it can in the synchronous case, but don't do that.